# How to get Email Message ID from Azure email service?

Tags: azure, email, imap, azure-communication-services

I'm trying to send email using azure email communication Python SDK

```py
poller = self.email_client.begin_send(
                message=payload,
            )

time_elapsed = 0

while not poller.done():
    logger.info("Email send poller status: " + poller.status())

    poller.wait(POLLER_WAIT_TIME)
    time_elapsed += POLLER_WAIT_TIME

    if time_elapsed > 18 * POLLER_WAIT_TIME:
        raise RuntimeError("Polling timed out.")

result = poller.result()
```

**Payload:**

```json
{
    "content": {
        "subject": "Sample Subject",
        "html": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n\n\n</head>\n<body>\n\n<div style=\"padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%\">\n<p>Hello Team,</p></div>\n</body>\n</html>"
    },
    "recipients": {
        "to": [
            {
                "address": "my_email.com",
                "displayName": "My Name"
            }
        ],
        "cc": [],
        "bcc": []
    },
    "senderAddress": "dillip@something.net",
    "attachments": []
}
```

**Result:**

```json
{
   "id":"570e68e8-0418-4cde-bd5e-49d9a9bf3f49",
   "status":"Succeeded",
   "error":null
}
```

I need message_id for various purposes, but I'm not getting message_id here from azure api, am i missing anything ?

How to get the message_id of the email sent?

Comment: You probably are intended to set it, not get it. Try adding "messageId": and then something like "<" a uuid "@something.net>" to the payload.

Comment: that's not working, tried this

Answer (score 0):

This code may be of interest to you

```
from azure.communication.email import EmailClient, EmailContent, 
EmailRecipients, EmailSender
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

# Initialize the EmailClient with your connection string
email_client = 
EmailClient.from_connection_string("your_connection_string_here")

# Construct the email message payload
email_content = EmailContent(subject="Sample Subject")
email_content.html = "<div><p>Hello Team,</p></div>"
recipients = EmailRecipients(to=[{"email": "recipient@example.com", 
"displayName": "Recipient Name"}])
sender = EmailSender(email="sender@example.com", display_name="Sender 
Name")

# Send the email
send_operation = email_client.send(email_content, recipients, sender)

# Wait for the send operation to complete and retrieve the result
send_result = send_operation.result()

# Extract the Message ID from the send result
message_id = send_result.message_id
print(f"Message ID: {message_id}")
```

[Retrieving Message ID from Azure Email Service](https://www.tempmail.us.com/en/azure/retrieving-message-id-from-azure-email-service)

Comment: this is not vaild with latest version of azure communication python package, there is no such method like "send" now, we've only "begin_send"